# Auth::check() takes more than 1 sec

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

With Laravel 5.1 Auth::check() takes more than 1 sec on my dev. computer.
I think that’s quite strange. What does it do for so much time??
Is that normal speed? Should I check something in my configuration or environment?
PS. I have Win 8.1 i5, 6 GB Ram

Comment: Normal speed is about 0-5ms for the first check (it has to do a DB query), and < .1ms for future checks.

Comment: unbelivable...
any advice to check something?

Comment: It has to do a DB query so you could check your database access speed.

Comment: Not at all. It doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a normal time unless you have a very absurdly huge users table.

Put this in the start of your routes.php file:

```
\DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
```

Put this in your view:

```
<pre>{{ var_dump(\DB::getQueryLog()) }}</pre>
```

And you'll be able to see all the queries, bindings and execution time for that request.

Compare the times between queries and you may have a clue about what is happening.

To do a Auth::check() laravel need to compare the info provided by the user cookie with the info in the user table (database query) and sessions info (if set to database, it will check the database also).

Comment: My users table is tiny, and developers MySQL server is locally installed. And what Auth:check() accesses database for?

Comment: I don't understand. Query log is empty:

array(0) {
}

Comment: @zhekaus I have edited the answer with some more info